# Keep user logged in with Facebook Phonegap plugin?

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is maddening.  HOW DO I KEEP A USER LOGGED IN WITH THE FACEBOOK PHONEGAP PLUGIN? I know that the API limit for an oauth token is 2 hours, but can you keep a user logged into a phonegap app so that they don't have to log back in every time they want to use it?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find out the answer to this question? Do you need to just re-sign in the user automatically when they load the app/page or is there another way?